# Disable alerts on docs in moss2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, alerts

We need to stop alerts from going out to our user base when we modify or upload revised documents into our document library. I tried disabling alerts and that stopped right away. However if we reanable the alerts still go out. Can anyone tell me what I can do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

When an alert is triggered, it's not handled right away. A copy is created and stored in the database. The timer service then picks it up and processes it. I just did a quick search to see if this queue could be accessed by object model code but all I'm seeing is SQL to query the SharePoint database directly.

From [this blog post](http://suguk.org/blogs/the_moss-pit/archive/2008/10/31/14854.aspx) it looks like a query (against the Content Database) to start with in order to find existing queued alerts would be:

```
SELECT 
   EventTime, 
   ItemName, 
   ItemFullUrl 
FROM 
   EventCache 
WHERE 
   ID > (SELECT Id FROM EventBatches)
```

Comment: @Clay Wright, be aware that modifying sharepoint database directly is unsupported. Selecting also has its own issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665755/how-do-i-query-the-sharepoint-database/1665791#1665791